# Pagination issue with tag.php

Tags: templates, pagination, query, tags

I use this code in `tag.php`:

```
 global $wp_query;
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
     $termsss = $wp_query->queried_object;
     $my_argsss = array (
        'post_type' => array('pavilion','post','catalog','tenders','services'),
        'tag' => $termsss->slug,
        'posts_per_page' =>'20',
        'paged' => $paged
     );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query -> query ($my_argsss);

     if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
     while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) { $wp_query->the_post(); 

     // your code!

     }
}
```

At first page, we can see every we want, but in another page returns 404 not found!
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never re-do the main query. Hook into `pre_get_posts` and *change* it. The following needs to go in your `functions.php` (putting in the template will mean it runs too late):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_tag() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );
        $wp_query->set( 'post_type', [
            'pavilion',
            'post',
            'catalog',
            'tenders',
            'services',
        ]);
    }
});
```

And now your template code should just be:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 

        // your code!
    }
}
```